# What is the main benefit of empy <> fragment in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, react-native

First of all I want to repeat again I am asking about its usage in `react-native` not `ReactJS`.
I am just confused, Is there any specific benefit for using `<>` instead `<View>` or `<SafeAreaView>` in `react-native` as the `root Component` ?

I have a large application with more than `100 components tree` for now the `root` is like below?

```
const App = () => (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    ...  // components tree
  </SafeAreaView>
);
```

So is there any benefit if I change it like the following code:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      ...  // components tree
    </SafeAreaView>
  </>
);
```

Why I am asking this? as I have searched on google I fount it in `reactjs` it is `faster` if we use it as the `root` Component, and also this time when I updated my `react-native version`, it is added to the `root` of `react-native template`.

Answer (score 1):

> A common pattern in React is for a component to return multiple elements. Fragments let you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to the DOM.

In your example , you don't really need to wrap your code with **Fragment** or <>. For example , separate component which returns multiple children then you may need to wrap with  as component have only one root node.

So if component's sole purpose is just to return multiple children ,rather than wrap with `<View>` with is extra node. Simple wrap with `<>` which won't add extra node in dom.

```
class NameandPosition extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <Text>AB</Text>
       <Text>Flutter Developer</Text>
     </>
    );
  }
}
```

Snack : https://snack.expo.io/rJVUW82ZI

Comment: Thank you, is that faster ?

Comment: @Muhammad Yes it is. But performance difference won't be noticeable rather than I'll say it is considered as best practices.